# Webview: how to open link in html loaded via "loadDataWithBaseURL"

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm opening a WebView with static html in my Android app. The html contains a link as well which currently gets opened in the system browser, i.e. the app is put in the background. How can I achieve opening that link in the WebView itself? I tried it with

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewclient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        // gets never called
    }
}
```

but that method is never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it works for you.

```
 private void loadWebView() {
        webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", "Loading...", true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl("http://yourWeb.com/");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                pd.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                try {
                    pd.dismiss();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: wow, that was quick, thank you! But I'm loading the data with `loadDataWithBaseUrl`, not `loadUrl`

Comment: Then use only webView client  `webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                pd.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                try {
                    pd.dismiss();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        });`